# How to assign a variable to the result of a promise?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

I've tried so many things so far. I want csvData to equal the result of the data (after it's gone through d3's csv function) but I can only console log the data inside the function and not ever save it to a variable to be used later. It's either save as a promise or continue to be an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

```
let csvData = [];

let loadData = async function (csvData) {
  await csv("data.csv", (d) => d).then(data => (csvData = data));
} 

loadData(csvData);

console.log(csvData);
```

Comment: Why not only -> `let csvData = await csv("data.csv")` ?

Comment: Using `await` and `then` in the same statement is meaningless. @NavoneelTalukdar solution should solve the problem

Comment: Then it says: "Error: Module format iife does not support top-level await. Use the "es" or "system" output formats rather."